# How do I convert leading and kerning expressed to CSS styles

Tags: fonts, css, kerning

I have been given a design / style guide for a website that has the fonts expressed in point (pt) measurements, and additional leading and kerning adjustments - e.g. 40pt font, 60pt leading, -30pt kerning.

I would like to use em, rather than pt or px in the CSS, and am assuming (using reset) a base font size of 16px. The core font size conversation I can do, but I don't know what to do with the leading and kerning?

(PS I do know that this means the font will render differently on different devices / browsers, I just need somewhere to start.)

[UPDATE: I have created a [google doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqIQZlVb9MACdElFY1gyTS1lU3hVZFhnYWsweVM3eHc&pli=1#gid=0) with the conversion of pt to px / em]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kerning equates to `.class { letter-spacing: Xem; }`

Leading equates to `.class { line-height: Xem; }`

use the exact same conversion you are using for the font size to get the correct em values. 1pt = 1px

Comment: Coming back to this v. late in the day - (and post a typography course) - kerning specifically relates to pairs of letters (e.g. AW, AY, etc.), and is distinct from 'tracking', which relates to the spacing between letters in general. The CSS style 'letter-spacing' refers to 'tracking', and *not* 'kerning', which is not directly manageable in CSS. There are JS libraries to help with this, and a not-very-well-supported CSS style `{text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}` which lets the browser optimise itself.

Comment: `word-spacing` equates to tracking.

Comment: Tracking[1] is the space between characters, not words. According to the formal definition of word and letter spacing[2], which makes letter-spacing the equivalent to tracking.

[1] http://www.adobe.com/uk/type/topics/glossary.html#tracking
[2] http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#spacing-props